# Different command outputs

Tags: bash, shell, assignment

[image]

I entered same command with a variable host. During 2nd time I entered blank space between host,= and $. Why it was trying to connect to a server ? Also, when I write like $(host name), I am getting error
 Host = not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
 centos

Comment: It would be useful to know what is the output of `hostname`?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Output is centos. For first time it gives output correctly when entered without space. But during second time as you can see it tries to connect to a server and then prints the output centos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must not be any spaces between a variable name and the equation mark. When there are spaces, the variable name is interpreted as a command, in this case the command `host` is run with parameters `=` and the host name.